# Am I allowed multiple entry to USA on a I-94W?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Driving to California from Mexico. Once in the US I am planing to fly for a week in Costa Rica, fly back to the US, then drive back to Mexico.
I recently was denied boarding a plane to go back to the US because I stayed more than a year in Peru as a green card holder.
I just want to visit for 3 months, entering by land on a I-94W form, and want to make sure I won't have trouble to fly back to the US, and drive back to Mexico.
I travel with a French passport.

Comment: I think you are confusing quite a few things. An I-94W is just a form, it’s still up to the CBP official to decide if they want to let you in or not. You cannot fly to the US without an ESTA or a visa. Do you have either of those?

Comment: @PeterM aren't "to California from Mexico" and "from Mexico to California" the same thing?

Comment: @mlc stupidity strikes again

Comment: Have you formally abandoned your status as a lawful permanent resident of the US?  Do you intend to?  Being away for more than a year means that you can't use your green card to enter the US, but it does not cause you to lose your LPR status automatically.

Comment: We're you denied boarding boarding by airline staff or by a US customs official at s preclearance facility?

Comment: I was denied boarding the plane by airline staff.

Comment: I haven't formally abandoned my LPR status but was still denied borading the plane to go back to the US!

Comment: The airline was correct to deny boarding since your green card is not valid for entry into the United States after an absence of more than one year.  But it's not clear what itinerary you have in mind; you seem to say that you want to visit the US for three months and then fly back to the US.  The best course of action also depends on whether you want to renounce your LPR status or maintain it. Can you edit the question to describe your itinerary more precisely and mention whether you plan to relinquish your green card? (If you include "@phoog" when you reply, I will be notified of the reply.)

Comment: @phoog I am changing my plans; I am still going to drive from Mexico to the US with with a tourist visa, plan to stay there for 3 months while I am hoping to find a solution to my green card as I don't want to loose my LRP. Will fly to Costa Rica when I am back in Mexico....

Comment: @ZoraCoeurdeRoy they won't let you in as a tourist unless you formally relinquish your LPR status, and they won't let you in as an LPR unless you can make a successful case that you haven't abandoned your residence in the US.  To retain your green card, you should find a good immigration lawyer and not visit the US unless your lawyer says it's okay.

Comment: @phoog are you sure about that?

Comment: @ZoraCoeurdeRoy yes.  You cannot enter the US as a nonimmigrant when you are a lawful permanent resident because an LPR is an immigrant.  In order to enter as a tourist, therefore, it must first be established that you are not a lawful permanent resident,

Comment: @ZoraCoeurdeRoy there is an episode of [Homeland Security USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeland_Security_USA) (or perhaps of a similar show if one exists) in which this happened to a Russian (if I recall correctly) woman who had moved away from the US without relinquishing her LPR status.  The officer had her fill out the [I-407 form](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407) as a prerequisite to admitting her as a tourist.  I couldn't find a detailed enough set of episode summaries to figure out which episode it was, and I don't have time to watch them right now.

Comment: Thank you @phoog! I hear different things from different people...as I am in Tijuana now I may as well try! If they don’t let me in, i’ll stay in Mexico and try to resolve my free card situation from here....